# Click / MouseOver only being triggered on part of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://redcode.bits2pieces.co.cc/mdm/#investment

In the second row of images, the rollover effect is only being invoked when the cursor is moved over the top one-fifth if the image. I'm facing the same problem if I move the event handler from the  to the parent div.

The rollover is working fine in the first row of images.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The hover isn't working at all on FF 3.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your "wrapper" is covering the bottom half of the 2nd row of images.

This div:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="margin-top: 370px">
```

Try increasing the margin-top to at least 500px, that should move it out of the way.

Answer (score 3):

That's happening because your <div class="wrapper" ...> is overlaping second row.

[wrapper http://office.gold.lv/tmp/wrapper.png](http://office.gold.lv/tmp/wrapper.png).